# Get a list of installed applications

Tags: c++, windows, api, com

I'm trying to build a list of installed applications, similar to the list in Add/Remove Programs list in the control panel.
I've tried using `Win32_Product WMI Class` and `MsiEnumProducts`.
Both of them outputted very similar outputs but both were missing programs that are in Add/Remove Programs. For example I know I have `Adobe Flash Player` installed, but it was on neither of these lists.

I've been trying to avoid reading the registry, because I've read that it's better to use some API to retrieve the list, but none of the methods I've found so far have worked.

Is there any other built in API/COM methods that could work? Or should I just try to read everything from the registry?

ALSO...
There are programs in the registry that are not in the Add/Remove Programs list, for example I have `Microsoft Security Essentials` installed. In the registry there is an entry to uninstall `Microsoft Antimalware`, which I'm assuming is apart of `Microsoft Security Essentials` but its not in the Add/Remove Programs list and I see no do-not-display value of any kind. (Part of the reason I want to use an API of some kind)

Comment: Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the `SystemComponent` value hides it from the Add/Remove program list.

And since I can't find any other API to use, I'm just going to enumerate the registry.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the same items as in the "Programs and Features" list, you can just bind to the folder and ask for its contents. Here is the scripting version:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var programsFolder = shell.Namespace("::{26EE0668-A00A-44D7-9371-BEB064C98683}\\0\\::{7b81be6a-ce2b-4676-a29e-eb907a5126c5}");
var items = programsFolder.Items();
for (var i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
 var item = items.Item(i);
 WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The C++ version of this involves a lot more typing but the idea is the same.